# how to prevent idea auto resolve maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to idea and maven ,I  find that every time, when I am edit the dependency in the pom.xml ,before I finished writing, idea tryed to resolve the dependency and create some folder in my native repo , for example , when I am edit the dependency, and it looks like this now

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-a</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

idea has create a folder in my native repo like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Qq4.png),how to prevent it and I have set my setting like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmOKV.png),but it seems no use, and the file is auto saved as usual

Comment: question, why do you not want the dependency resolved?  it seems counter-intuitive

Comment: I mean I don't want the dependency resolved before I finish it, because it will create some folder in my native repo that is no use

Comment: your question is not clear - before you finish what? - it creates a folder, to download the dependencies into your project (since you are saying your project depends on them) - I guess instead of waiting until compile time (when it would have to download all dependencies, it does it one at a time as they get added/detected) - I must be missing something here

Comment: the dependency get's added to the classpath as well. Maybe read up on maven - the folder is definitely of use and is valid.

Comment: before I finished the dependency, that is the dependency has not edit completely. and the folder created is no use,I cannot post the image here, you can watch it by this[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Qq4.png)link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you have enabled the "Import Maven projects automatically" option. To disable it, go to `Preferences... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing`, then uncheck the option from there, like so:

[image: Preferences Screenshot]

After doing so, it will be up to you to run the imports when you're ready. To import manually, right-click your project in the Project view, then click `Maven > Reimport`:

[image: Context Menu Screenshot]

Comment: It works ! thanks . and I want to ask that how to disable auto save in idea, I   have set the synchronization like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmOKV.png)

Comment: Not sure about that one. However, it seems like that question is unrelated to this one, so I would just ask a new question about autosaving. Also, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. :)